# Why do people say “Why don’t you not?”

Tags: double-negation, hiberno-english

Why do people say “Why don’t you not?” — what is meant by that? It seems especially to be a Dublin thing.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. I've added a "What does that mean?" part because there is no answer to **why** anyone would say it. Even now I suspect that the answer is something like "That's part of the Irish dialect of English, and simply means *Why don't you [do that]?*"

Comment: Can you give more context? There are potentially lots of situations where that could be said; we don't know what exactly troubles you about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not Irish, but I would understand this as a (rather rude) way of telling someone not to do something that they have just suggested doing with the phrase, "Why don't I...?"

"Why don't I tell you about my wonderful holiday?" 
"Why don't you not!"

I must stress that this would end the conversation (and possibly the friendship, if any!) and would be very rude.

Answer (score 1):

I would read it, in context of just having discussed some action, as “why don’t you not [do that]?”, or, more clearly, “why don’t you do something other than that?”.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that dialect myself, but [Raymond Hickey claims](http://books.google.com/books?id=TZK9cSYRrjMC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=irish%20english%20negative%20concord&source=bl&ots=Aq01bOE23t&sig=5nptInK0yWEVjbFTFlk2FSqiMRM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TKjEUdPLG5LL0gH41oGQCg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=irish%20english%20negative%20concord&f=false) that Irish English (unlike most of the "prestige dialects" of English) uses [Negative Concord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative#Two_or_more_negatives_resolving_to_a_negative).

This means that multiple negatives in a sentence meerly intensifies the negativity. So this would be a somewhat more emphatic way of saying "Why don't you?"

Answer (score 0):

It means why can't you do some other thing than what you/they wanted you to do.